# Gnome 3 Window Decoration

Tags: 12.10, gnome

Is there a way to disable, on a per application basis, the window decoration associated with gnome?

In this case, in particular it's windows associated with PlayonLinux/Wine.

I still have to use MS Office for some things, however infrequently, and it seems that most of the functionality is "cut off" by Gnomes window decoration. Here's an example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

In PlayOnLinux, right click the program, click "Configure Wine", move to the graphics tab and deselect "Allow window manager to decorate the windows"

[image]